# Using LocalDb for unit test with EF Core project + Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, unit-testing, localdb, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm using localdb for unit tests. Tests are executed in certain order (those that are out of order are expected to fail).

In the past, I have experimented with InMemory, but that failed as it's not relational and SQLite failed as some of requests we have do not return data (`List<Guid>().Contains(Guid)`)

Before executing tests, I have static method that set's up the tests environment.

Connection string for localDb:

```
private static string LocalDBConnection = "Server=(localdb)\\DbInstance;Database=UnitTest; Integrated security=True";
```

`DbInstance` is created using `MartinCostelo.SlLocalDb...`

After that I create service provider, and register `dbContext`.

To ensure I have clean start every time, I drop and recreate test DB on every run:

```
        dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

This code is executing perfectly on every computer in office. It creates UnitTest db in user local folder.

But, when I try to build solution on Azure pipeline, it does not create db, as the environment is different. I should create db under same folder where tests are executed, but...

Connection string which is using db location:

```
private static string LocalDBConnection = "Server=(localdb)\\DbInstance;Database=UnitTest; Integrated security=True; AttachDBFilename=.\\UnitTest.mdf";
```

This should create db in same location where tests are executed.

EF Core executest ensuredeleted and ensurecreated
EnsureDeleted returns false (it failed, but it does not complicate things)
EnsureCreated translates to SQL as:

```
CREATE DATABASE [UnitTest]
ON (NAME = N'UnitTest', FILENAME = N'C:\Dev\somefolders\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\UnitTest.mdf')
LOG ON (NAME = N'UnitTest_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Dev\somefolders\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\UnitTest_log.ldf');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (57ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') <> 5
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [UnitTest] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
END;
```

And execution of this throws SqlException:
Cannot attach the file '.\UnitTest.mdf' as database 'UnitTest'.

UPDATE:

`EnsureCreated` actually creates the database (it becomes visible in SQL Server Management Studio), but it waits for timeout and after that throws exception.

If I stop test execution and re run it again (database exists on disk), then `EnsureCreated` throws exception instantly:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
> Database 'UnitTest' already exists. Choose a different database name.

As previously, `EnsureDeleted` did not do its job.

And all troubles are related to using `AttachDbFilename` in connection string...

Any ideas on how to solve this, as my Azure build will not work with tests in this setup :-)

Thanks
kzendra

Comment: this expands on the answer provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#:~:text=EF%20Core%20comes%20with%20an%20in-memory%20database%20that,testing%20applications%20that%20use%20EF%20Core%20.%20Specifically%3A

Comment: @mvermef As stated below, SQLite does not work with some of queries writen in code  and as for EF Core InMemory, from the link you provided:
EF Core comes with an in-memory database that we use for internal testing of EF Core itself. This database is in general not suitable for testing applications that use EF Core.

Comment: Well aware of the abilities for sqlite. I was merely adding the documentation to back up what MS suggests

Answer (score -2):

It is recommended to use [SQLite in memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite) for integration testing Entity Framewor Core. You should fix the tests that are failing instead of using LocalDb.

Example:

```cs
    public class SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest : ItemsControllerTest, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly DbConnection _connection;

        public SqliteInMemoryItemsControllerTest()
            : base(
                new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ItemsContext>()
                    .UseSqlite(CreateInMemoryDatabase())
                    .Options)
        {
            _connection = RelationalOptionsExtension.Extract(ContextOptions).Connection;
        }

        private static DbConnection CreateInMemoryDatabase()
        {
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=:memory:");

            connection.Open();
            
            return connection;
        }

        public void Dispose() => _connection.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Some of my queries do not work in SQLite:

query = query.Where(x=> guids.Contains(x.Id));
guids is List<Guid> in this case.

Seems EF core translate it to list of strings, but is using uppercase and is comparing them to lowercase Guid from SQLite db, which does not return result...